# Looking for fastest and least-programming-required path to implement a web site with user submitted content with voting and comments

Tags: templates, voting

I'm looking to throw up a web site that supports user submitted entries and allows voting and comments. Similar in form and function to [FMyLife](http://fmylife.com).

Basic requirements of site:

- Users can submit text entries - generally 1 liners
- Enters can be up or down voted
- Comments allowed - presentation collapseable

Would like the fastest path possible. Ideal solution is configurable vs requirement for programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you had a look at [Drupal](http://drupal.org/)?  You can get a site up and running pretty quickly, it's very configurable, and it'll allow you to add to the site you're proposing if it grows...

Comment: I was going to suggest Drupal also. You can get modules to satisfy all of your requirements.

Comment: Thanks guys do i need php experience? And is there a significant learning curve if i've never use drupal before?

Comment: @Howiecamp - PHP not required, unless you want to write your own modules.  Some experience setting up a LAMP server would be useful, but I did it from scratch and it was ok...